# MySQL in discord.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm setting up a bot to work with a MySQL Database.
It worked beforehand and now after I've added the MySQL code it isn't working:

```
(node:12312) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
    at C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\MuffinMod Data\MuffinMod - Recode\Bot\events\ready.js:4:20
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\MuffinMod Data\MuffinMod - Recode\Bot\events\ready.js:3:25)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at WebSocketManager.triggerClientReady (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\MuffinMod Data\MuffinMod - Recode\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:431:17)
    at WebSocketManager.checkShardsReady (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\MuffinMod Data\MuffinMod - Recode\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:415:10)
    at WebSocketShard.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\MuffinMod Data\MuffinMod - Recode\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:197:14)
    at WebSocketShard.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at WebSocketShard.checkReady (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\MuffinMod Data\MuffinMod - Recode\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:475:12)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\MuffinMod Data\MuffinMod - Recode\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:447:16)
(node:12312) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function 
without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)       
(node:12312) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

index.js:

```
require('dotenv').config();

//Database
let connection;
(async () => {
    connection = await require('./database/db.js');
})();
//Bot
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'], restRequestTimeout: 50000 });
const guildSettings = new Map();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.events = new Discord.Collection();
const DisTube = require('distube');
client.distube = new DisTube(client, { searchSongs: false, emitNewSongOnly: true });
['command', 'event'].forEach(handler =>{
    require(`./Bot/handlers/${handler}`)(client, Discord, connection);
});
await client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

ready.js:

```
module.exports = async(Discord, client, connection) => {
    console.log(`Bot online. (${client.user.tag})`);
    client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
        connection.query(
            `SELECT * FROM GuildConfigurable WHERE guildID = ${guild.id}`
        ).then(result => {
            guildSettings.set(guild.id, result[0][0]);
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    });
}
```

db.js:

```
const sql = require('mysql2/promise');
module.exports = sql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    user: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
})
.then(()=>console.log(`Connected to MySQL Database.`))
.catch(err=>console.error(err));
```

I think it's an error of the ready.js file being executed before the db.js file can return the connection  no idea how to fix it though.
Thanks

Comment: tip unrelated to your problem, use `SELECT id FROM GuildConfigurable WHERE guildID = ..` so the MySQL server doesn't waste bandwidth and effort returning data that isn't needed.

Comment: The error comes from your `ready.js`, `connection` is returning undefined.

Comment: @Elitezen Yea I think that the bot is getting logged in and the ready.js is executing before the db.js can return the database connection

Answer (score 0):

As your `async` method only sets the `connection` variable once the promise is resolved, it will still be undefined at the point you're using it to set up the event handlers.

You can either keep `connection` as a promise that is awaited each time it's needed, or move is creation to be in the same async function as it's consumers (as below)

```
require('dotenv').config();

//Bot
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'], restRequestTimeout: 50000 });
const guildSettings = new Map();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.events = new Discord.Collection();
const DisTube = require('distube');
client.distube = new DisTube(client, { searchSongs: false, emitNewSongOnly: true });

(async () => {
    const connection = await require('./database/db.js');

    ['command', 'event'].forEach(handler =>{
      require(`./Bot/handlers/${handler}`)(client, Discord, connection);
});

    await client.login(process.env.TOKEN);

})();
```

In `db.js` you also need to return the `connection` from the final step of the `Promise` chain:

```
const sql = require('mysql2/promise');
module.exports = sql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    user: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
})
.then((connection) => {
    console.log(`Connected to MySQL Database.`);
    return connection;
})
.catch(err=>console.error(err));
```

Comment: Just noticed `connection` will still be `undefined` because it's not returned from `db.js` - updated the answer accordingly